# Изменить стиль после нажатия на ссылку

Tags: javascript, функции, css

Есть ссылка, внутри нее два span'а.
Нужно при нажатии на ссылку поменять класс самой ссылки, а также поменять свойство display у span'ов. Или любым другим способом спрятать span1 и на его месте показать span2.

```
<a class="link-1" href="url" id="link-<? echo $id ?>" onclick="linkclass(id);spandisplay();">
<span style="display:inline" class="span1">Текст1</span>
<span style="display:none" class="span2">Текст2</span></a>
```

После клика на выходе нужно получить что-то вроде этого:

```
<a class="link-2" href="url" id="link-<? echo $id ?>" onclick="linkclass(id);spandisplay();">
<span style="display:none" class="span1">Текст1</span>
<span style="display:inline" class="span2">Текст2</span></a>
```

Сделал так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function linkclass(id){
    document.getElementById(id).className = 'link-2';
}
function spandisplay(){
    document.getElementByClassName('span1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementByClassName('span2').style.display = 'inline';
}</script>
```

Функция spandisplay не работает.

Погуглил еще, оказывается, вообще нет такого метода getElementByClassName...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto), так работает:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("span1")[0].style.display = 'none';
```

Но. Так и не разобрался, как задать определение нужного элемента. На странице таких ссылок несколько.

В общем, сделал все проще: оставил span1, а при клике на ссылку через innerHTML подставляю span2 с необходимым содержимым. Не знаю, насколько так лучше или хуже, на выходе результат требуемый получил.

```
function spanreplace(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<span class="span2">text</span>';  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

getElement**s**ByClassName - получится nodeList, это массивоподобный живой объект. Возьмите нулевой элемент либо сделайте по нему перебор, и получите то, что хотите.